# css gradient rectangle with round beneath

Tags: css, gradient

I'm trying to achieve the following design but I can't get the circle and rectangle gradient to match. I've looked it up and could not find anything helpful...

This is more obvious when you test different screen ratio, the difference will increase/decrease as you resize the window.

[Sample design with mismatching gradients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cepA.png)

Here is a plunker of the current implementation

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/D6v7qmzze43dC6ch

How can I get/compute the circle's gradient to make it match perfectly the rectangle's one ?

Is there another approach to this problem ?

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it working like this, it uses clipping but it's looking great, thanks anyway

```css
/* from flex-layout (fxLayout="row" fxlayoutalign="center stretch") */
.flex-layout {
  display: flex;
  place-content: stretch stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.toolbar-header {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #00b598, #b3eade);
  height: 200px; /* picture size including border */
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.rectangle-mask {
  clip-path: inset(0px 0px 30px 0px);
}

.circle-mask {
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  clip-path: circle(100px at center);
}

.picture {
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  clip-path: circle(85px at center);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
 <script src="lib/script.js">

 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="flex-layout" role="heading">
  <div class="toolbar-header rectangle-mask"></div>
  <div class="toolbar-header circle-mask">
   <img class="picture" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Header picture"/>
  </div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Something</title>
  </head>

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .mainDiv {
      margin: auto;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .header {
      background: #2ac2a8;
      background: linear-gradient(0deg,#2ac2a8 0%, #8fe2d2 80%);
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg,#2ac2a8 0%, #8fe2d2 80%);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg,#2ac2a8 0%, #8fe2d2 80%);
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      position: absolute;
    }

    .circlePhoto {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background: #CCCCCC;
      border: 25px solid #37c8b0;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: auto;
      position: relative;
      top: 100px;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div class="mainDiv">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="circlePhoto"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The circle must be a gradient too that matches the one of the rectangle header so that won't do

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "45 deg"

```
.toolbar-header {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #00b598, #b3eade);
 }

.picture {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #4dc4ac, #6ddac8);
 }
```

put "to right" instead

```
.toolbar-header {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #00b598, #b3eade);
 }

.picture {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #4dc4ac, #6ddac8);
 }
```

or "to top right"